# HighCharts error #17 for pyramid chart angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, highcharts

I am building an angular app. I need a pyramid chart which I am populating from api call.Pyramid Chart doesn't load. It throws HighCharts Error#17 when run.
Pyramid uses highchart /modules/funnel.js and expoting.js

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TestSubTypeSummaryService } from '../services/testSubTypeSummary.service';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core'
var Highcharts = require('highcharts');
require ('funnel');
require('exporting');
var completeArray : any[] = [];
@Component({
    selector : 'pyramid-chart',
    template : `
        <div id="pyramid-div" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    `
})
export class PyramidChart {
    foo:any;
    constructor(private fsService : TestSubTypeSummaryService){

    };

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.getTestSubTypeSummary();
    }

    getTestSubTypeSummary() : void{
        this.fsService.getTestSubTypeSummary().subscribe( data => {
            console.log("Chart Data: "+JSON.stringify(data));
            this.parseData(data);
              this.renderChart();
        });
    }

    parseData(data : any) : void{
        var count = data.length;
        for(var i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
            var funcObjArray : [string,number];
            var typeName = data[i].testSubTypeName;
            var typeCount = data[i].testSubTypeCount
            funcObjArray = [typeName,typeCount];
            completeArray.push(funcObjArray);       
        }
    }

    renderChart() : void{
        Highcharts.chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo : 'pyramid-div',
            type: 'pyramid',
            marginRight: 100
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Test pyramid',
            x: -50
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black',
                    softConnector: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tests',
            data: completeArray
        }]
    });

    }
}
```

Comment: looks like funnel/exporting modules are not loaded properly. How did you installed them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below changes will work.

```
require('funnel')(HighCharts);
require('exporting')(HighCharts);
```

Make sure you have Highcharts installed , if not install it by using

```
npm install highcharts
```

Also add angular bundle for highcharts in  system.config.js

```
map:{
    'highcharts': 'node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js',
    'exporting': 'node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js',
    'funnel': 'node_modules/highcharts/modules/funnel.js'
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I m using angular 6, same issue I'm getting type:"pyramid" is saying 
ERROR Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17, however when I dug into the npm module I saw the pyramid type is present therein npm highchart.?

Comment: Got the fix after some R&D in Highchart,

    import { Chart, Highcharts } from 'angular-highcharts';
    declare var require: any;
    require('highcharts/modules/funnel')(Highcharts);

Answer (score 1):

For Angular 6 or those who are using web pack can require funnel like this,

```
import { Chart, Highcharts } from 'angular-highcharts';
declare var require: any;
require('highcharts/modules/funnel')(Highcharts);
```